# delete image before update

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, file-upload

```
string url = img_prev.ImageUrl.ToString();
if (!url.Equals(""))
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(url))
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + url);
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

I fond one way to delete the image before update but it still not working. my url path like this:

```
../uploadimages/21-2-2013-14-55-49-P1120011.JPG
```

Comment: I suspect the image is in use the moment you try to delete it, that's why it can't be deleted.

Comment: although url get the path image but when I bug this line if (System.IO.File.Exists(url))  it's return false

Comment: `System.IO.File.Exists(string path)` returns false, when the file does not exist or the path is invalid [(Source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx), which is why I assume your `url` is invalid (is it a path (`c:\somePath`) or is it _really_ a URL (`www.someURL.com`)?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're using a web URL as argument, which won't work with `System.IO.File.Exists()`, use this instead:

```
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(filePath)))
```

[System.IO.File.Exists returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772724/system-io-file-exists-returns-false)